# knockoutjs nested observable object and coffeescript classes

Tags: nested, coffeescript, knockout.js, observable

I have a player class and viewmodel

```
class Player
    constructor: ->
        @boat = ko.observable null

class Boat
    constructor: (@id) ->

class ViewModel
    player: ko.observable
```

in html

```
<div data-bind="if: player">
        <div data-bind="template: {name: 't_me', data: player}"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/html" id="t_me">
    <span>player boat
        <span data-bind="if: boat()">            
            <b data-bind="text: boat().id"></b>
        </span>        
    </span>
</script>
```

now in script i try to set boat to plyer

```
vm = new ViewMode()
ko.applyBindings vm
vm.player new Player()
vm.player.boat new Boat(1)
```

And I can't make View react on this changes any ideas?

Comment: What is the console error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I see with your code is lack of parens on the `vm.player` observable. (assuming that `vm = new ViewMode()` is a typo)

I believe the last line should be: `vm.player().boat new Boat(1)`